# BeautifulSoup returns multiple Div values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any help is appreciated!

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(updated_url, "lxml")
confStar = soup1.find_all('div', attrs={'data-testid': 'ConfidenceRating'})
print(confStar)
```

Above is the snippet of code I am having issues with. Every time I run my program it returns 15 divs when I only want one. I know it is running through each url item and returning all my values, but I cant figure out how I would go about only showing one pages results at a time.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
games = {}
endUrl = 0

# ---------------------------PickWise Game Grabber-------------------------------------------------#
page = requests.get("https://www.pickswise.com/nfl/", headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
box = soup1.find_all("div", class_="predictions_eventGrid__xDIPy")

game_urls = []
bb = []
info = {f"Game{endUrl}": {"Record": {"team1": "",
                                         "team2": ""},
                              "Projected W": "",
                              "Trust Factor": 0,
                              "+/-": 0,
                              }
            }

# ----- Grabs all URLs for the upcoming games and adds it to game_urls list.
for time in box:
    links = time.find('div', class_='EventGrid_eventContainer__39T3x')
    for urls in links:
        url = urls.get('href')
        game_urls.append(url)

# ------------Visits each game url and populated dict with info------------------------#
for i in game_urls:
    endUrl += 1
    # ----- Finds URLS and fills data from webpage ---- #
    updated_url = requests.get(f"https://www.pickswise.com{i}").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(updated_url, "lxml")
    box = soup.find_all('div', class_="PredictionHeaderTeam_name__Pf64F")
    record = soup.find('table', class_="PredictionEnhancedInfo_predictionEnhancedInfo__35ubN")
    test = soup.find('div', class_="PredictionHeaderTeam_enhancedInfo__3lhgr")

    # ------------Gets the confidence rating for each team on PickWise-------------------
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(updated_url, "lxml")
    confStar = soup1.find_all('div', attrs={'data-testid': 'ConfidenceRating'})
    print(confStar)
```

Below is the style of output I am looking for, yet it produces 15. (One for each NFL team)

```
[<div data-testid="ConfidenceRating"><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_tertiary__eho3l ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_empty__3yDPX ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_empty__3yDPX ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span></div>, <div data-testid="ConfidenceRating"><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_tertiary__eho3l ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_tertiary__eho3l ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_empty__3yDPX ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span></div>, <div data-testid="ConfidenceRating"><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_tertiary__eho3l ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_tertiary__eho3l ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span><span aria-label="icon-filled-star" class="Icon_icon__13A6L Icon_small__1lKlR Icon_icon-filled-star__1HGwq Icon_empty__3yDPX ConfidenceRating_star__pr0wt" data-testid="Icon" role="img"></span></div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. probabably better seperate this `updated_url = requests.get(f"https://www.pickswise.com{i}").text` to make it little more readable code
2. no need to create 2 soup objects from the same html (as you do with `soup` and `soup1`
3. `find_all()` will return, as it states ALL those found elements. If you want just the first, us `.find()` or pull out the first element from that list that is returned from the `.find_all()`.
4. Usually if I have a counter, similar to what you are doing with the `endUrl` count, I would just use `enumerate()` to handle that

**Code:**

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


# ---------------------------PickWise Game Grabber-------------------------------------------------#
url = "https://www.pickswise.com/nfl/"

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')


# ----- Grabs all URLs for the upcoming games and adds it to game_urls list.
game_urls = []
games = soup.find_all('a', {'data-testid':'EventInfo'})
game_urls = [a['href'] for a in games]


# ------------Visits each game url and populated dict with info------------------------#
rows = []
for endUrl, link in enumerate(game_urls, start=1):
    # ----- Finds URLS and fills data from webpage ---- #
    updated_url = f"https://www.pickswise.com{link}"
    
    response = requests.get(updated_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    
    # ------------Gets the confidence rating for each team on PickWise-------------------
    records = soup.find('td', text='Record')
    team_1_record = records.find_previous('td').text
    team_2_record = records.find_next('td').text
    
    spread = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('SelectionInfo_outcome.*')})[0].find(text=True)
    projectedW = spread
    
    confidence = soup.find('div', {'data-testid':'ConfidenceRating'})
    stars = confidence.find_all('span')
    starsFilled = len([x for x in stars if 'empty' not in ' '.join(x['class'])])
    
    over_under = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('SelectionInfo_outcome.*')})[1].find(text=True)
    
    data = {
        f"Game{endUrl}": {
            "Records": {
                "team1":team_1_record,
                "team2":team_2_record
                        },
            "Projected W":projectedW,
            "Trust Factor": starsFilled,
            "+/-": over_under
            }
        }
    
    rows.append(data)
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

Note I ran this after all Sunday games were done, so it'll only return the 2 remaing MNF games.

```
{'Game1': {'Records': {'team1': '0-1', 'team2': '1-0'}, 'Projected W': 'TEN Titans +10.0', 'Trust Factor': 1, '+/-': 'Under 48.0'}}
{'Game2': {'Records': {'team1': '1-0', 'team2': '1-0'}, 'Projected W': 'MIN Vikings +2.5', 'Trust Factor': 3, '+/-': 'Over 50.5'}}
```

Comment: 1: I realized I had headers already defined at the top so I cut it out completely.
2: I have soup1 for other functions in my code that I didn't add since it would be pretty big.
3: You would think calling find() would solve my issue or just pulling the first two elements, but it doesn't and even if you change it to what you have it still pulls all 15 games worth.

Comment: Ya it pulls 15 games worth because you are iterating through the 15 game urls. It's not clear exactly what your expected output should be. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can only make assumptions as to what you're after here. But adjusted my code to match that. See if that's close to what you are after.